# Bash: Split up loop based on number of enumerations to process several files

Tags: bash, loops, split

In need to process a bunch of files in bash and split up the process based on the number of enumerations. I'd like to process first 1000 files and then another 1000 files and stop if the limit of 2000 files is exceeded. In python I would do something like this:

```
for e,any_file in enumerate("some_files"):
    if e<1000: # for the first 1000 files
        print(any_file) # or do anything you want
    else:
        if e<2000: # for the second 1000 files
            print(any_file)
        else:
            print("exceeded maximum limit!")
```

is there anything similar for the bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter:

```
e=1  ## Counter
for f in /path/*; do
    if (( e < 1000 )); then
        echo "$f"
    else
        if (( e < 2000 )); then
            echo "$f"
        else
            echo "exceeded maximum limit!"
        fi
    fi
    (( ++e ))
done
```

Or an array:

```
files=(0 /path/*); unset 'files[0]'
for e in "${!files[@]}"; do
    f=${files[e]}
    ...
done
```

You can also create an array from an enumerator's output like `find` with process substitution and `readarray`:

```
readarray -O 1 -t files < <(exec find ...)
```

Refer to the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) (`man bash`) for everything. See `help` and `help <command>` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  the code you provided only works for me if I set `e=0` outside the loop and then `e=$e+1` inside the loop to make the enumerator work.

Comment: @joaoal Yes I forgot to increment the counter. I now made an update. It's also your option if you want to start your counter as 0 or 1. If you want to start at 0, you'd have to increment the counter first before processing.